# ORMLite - Handling Many-to-Many Relations I Got from JSON Source

Tags: java, android, json, gson, ormlite

Ľet's say I've got two API calls. One gets Foos referencing some Bars:

```
{"foos":[{"id":1,"barIDs":[4,5,6]},{"id":2,"barIDs":[1,2,3]}]}
```

Other one gets Bars referencing Foos:

```
{"bars":[{"id":1,"fooIDs":[4,5,6]},{"id":2,"fooIDs":[1,2,3]}]}
```

GSON got it right, now I have two Foo and two Bar objects, both referencing an array of foreign ids. Now I'm trying to get this persistent, but have no luck doing so, since I only have ID references, not the real objects. I got about this far with Foo:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "foos")
public class Foo {
    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "id")
    private long id;

    public ArrayList<Long> barIDs;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, foreignFieldName = "barIDs")
    public ForeignCollection<Bar> bars;
}
```

(Bar is pretty much the same)

When I try to run the code, this is what I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class com.example.ormlite.entities.Bar
    for field 'bars' column-name does not contain a foreign field named 'barIDs'
    of class com.example.ormlite.entities.Foo
```

So I have tried many different combinations of cross-annotations, filling it various fields, but obviously, I still don't understand how it works. Do you guys have any idea how to handle situations where I only have ID references and not the actual children inside? I'm starting to be kinda desperate with ORMLite, so if I can not get it right, I will just use the SQLite directly, but I would really love to learn how to work with it.

Thank you!